# Yasnippets: loading two major modes (`org-mode` and `LaTeX`)

Tags: org-mode, init-file, latex, yasnippet

I'm trying to load the `yasnippets` for the `LaTeX` mode every time I open an `org` file.

Is it possible? How can this be achieved?

Comment: Only one major mode is active at a time. Check to see if either of those major modes has a corresponding minor mode that you can use at the same time as the other major mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can load an additional modes via `yas-activate-extra-mode` in the hook of the major mode (it also works with `yas-global-mode` turned on).

Just copy-paste following elisp snippet into your init file:

```el
(defun my-org-latex-yas ()
  "Activate org and LaTeX yas expansion in org-mode buffers."
  (yas-minor-mode)
  (yas-activate-extra-mode 'latex-mode))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my-org-latex-yas)
```

Tested with:

- GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.20) of 2017-09-11
- yasnippet-20180124.1445
- yasnippet-snippets-20180122.521

Answer (score 1):

You can see what the [yasnippet repo has to say about this](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/blob/5cbdbf0d2015540c59ed8ee0fcf4788effdf75b6/doc/snippet-organization.org#the-yas-parents-file).

Basically, if you put a `.yas-parents` file (yes, a hidden file) inside your `snippets/org-mode/` directory and as the content of said file you put `latex-mode` the latex snippets will also be available in org-mode. This approach does not require any lisp and it is very simple to share many snippets across many different modes (by simply listing more modes in the `.yas-parents` file).