# Activating Latex snippets in org mode

Tags: org-mode

I have downloaded the yasnippet package which works very nicely for my Latex files. However, I often use Org mode to write my Latex documents.

The latex snippets from yasnipet dont seem to be "active" in org-mode. i.e. typing `begin` and pressing `tab` does not expand into `\begin{..} \end{..}`

How can I make the Latex yasnippets active in Org mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yasnippets: loading two major modes (\`org-mode\` and \`LaTeX\`)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38429/yasnippets-loading-two-major-modes-org-mode-and-latex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how to do it directly in the org file, but if you are writing LaTeX in export blocks then you can use `org-edit-special`. For instance, with the point in the following export block

```
#+begin_export latex
LaTeX snippets 
#+end_export
```

`C-c '` runs the command `org-edit-special` and in this case a buffer is opened with the content `LaTeX snippets` and in this buffer you can use all commands and functions that you can use for your LaTeX files.

Answer (score 1):

As answered [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38429/yasnippets-loading-two-major-modes-org-mode-and-latex) you can active snippets for other major-modes with `yas-activate-extra-mode`